# Does Oracle Cloud Artifact Registry support Gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Currently, I'm using Gradle and I need repository to sore libraries.

My question is: Does Oracle Cloud Artifact Registry support Gradle?

I searched in https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/artifacts/manage-artifacts.htm. I only saw it supports Console, Oracle Cloud Infrastructure CLI, or REST APIs

I want to know any guideline documents to help me using  Oracle Cloud Artifact Registry with Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Officially I dont believe there is support. However you can get Maven and Gradle plugins.  for example - https://github.com/kordamp/oci-gradle-plugin